# How do I change a keyring password that no longer matches?

Tags: login, keyrings

I have a system to learn on and I am new to Linux. I deleted the shared directory thinking the login keyring was there. Then I updated, listed and deleted the `ftpmaster@ubuntu`, thinking that was the keyring keeping me from what I am trying to do - which is get online; I cannot type in the passphrase to my router without being asked to put in the old keyring, which I thought I knew btw.

Comment: An old closed thread says this about ~/.gnome2/keyrings/login.keyring; "If you just delete the keyring files mentioned above, you should be able to get your current password and keyring sync'd when the the file is automatically recreated. It will ask you for the password on the next keyring access, you can type the new one and it should stop bothering you." **Can someone please tell me what the command line would be for a brand new linux user?** Thank you.

Comment: You can type ```rm ~/.gnome2/keyrings/login.keyring``` to remove that file. It might be at ```~/.local/share/keyrings/login.keyring``` though. Alternatively, you can navigate to that file by displaying hidden (dot) files in your graphical file manager (usually ```ctrl-h```).

Comment: Many questions ask a similar thing with similar answers but this is the first answer I've found (from comment above) that actually says _where_ the keyring is located! Thank you!

Comment: I think I deserve to be an answer, anyhow I have no `.gnome2` and i am not in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Applications -> Accessories -> Passwords and Encryption Keys

Right-click on Passwords: login

Select “Change Password”

Enter your old login password (the one that it repeatedly asks for!) in the old password bit, and put your current login password in the new password fields.

And that’s all there is to it!